# Getting extra properties added automatically in the json response web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

```
{"Result":{"Myexpectedoutput":[{"Name":{"FirstName":"Test123"}}]},"Id":84,"Exception":null,"Status":5,"IsCanceled":false,"IsCompleted":true,"CreationOptions":0,"AsyncState":null,"IsFaulted":false}
```

The properties `Id,exception,status,IsCanceled,Iscompleted,CreationOptions,AsyncState,IsFaulted` are getting added automatically.

Comment: I dont want these extra properties to get added in the response.I just need the response that has only the properties that i have defined in my class

Comment: You have to show us more than this. What action creates this response, can you post that code? Seems like a `Task` is serialized. And please remove your comment above and put that text in the question to make it one complete question.

Comment: Issue is resolved. the method was returning the TASK object.